# Has the YouTube Product Dashboard stopped updating?

Tags: youtube-api

For years I have used the [YouTube Product Dashboard](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard) to view statistics for our app, but it seems to have stopped getting updates since January 16, 2013. We are using [version 2 of the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).

Has anyone else noticed this? Or can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Screenshot from my dashboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRGAc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be broken at the moment. I've let the teams responsible know about it.

(As per [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html), a better place to report outages and bugs with the API is the issue tracker, not Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Thanks! I was headed there but figured I'd see if the community knew anything first.